# pass a variable to the result of an asynchronous call method's

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

There is a `DataGrid` with data in the Net 4.0 App. For the selected row, I get the value of one of the columns and pass it to the asynchronous method of the WCF service. Is it possible to pass this value as a result this method?

```
btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)dgData.SelectedItem;
    rv["TimeBeg"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
    string val=rv["Id"].ToString();
    srAsync.ServClient clP = new srAsync.ServClient();
    clP.MethodCompleted += cl_MethodComplete;
    clP.MethodAsync(val);
}
```

After the call, the user can select another `DataGrid` Item, and call `Async` method for them, but in complete method I need to call another method with this value and update the rows `DataGrid`

```
private void cl_MethodComplete(object sender, srA.MethodCompletedEventArgs e) {
    rv["TimeEnd"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
    sr.ServClient clP = new sr.ServClient();
    clP.AnotherMethod(val);
    ...
```

Comment: so... do you get an error? is there a problem? what is the question?

Comment: the variable **rv** is not defined in the **cl_MethodComplete**. during query processing, the user can select a another row, but I need update prevous  selected Row

Comment: would you like to call `cl_MethodComplete` with a third argument, which would be the original rv in btn_Click?

Comment: I would not want to edit the methods of WCF service

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: how release this? I declare deleagte **Sub**, create empty method **cl_MethodComplete** with two param, but how get var **srA.MethodCompletedEventArgs  e** in **btn_Click**?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: yes, i get 5 error - require ";" , no define Sub etc.

Comment: Right, there was a mistake in my code. My apologies, I edited it, can you test it again?

Comment: no( , in *btn_Click* argument *e* has type *RoutedEventArgs*,  but the *cl_MethodComplete(sender, e, rv)* requires  e as srA.MethodCompletedEventArgs type

Comment: thankls !!!!  edit *cl_MethodComplete(sender, e, rv)* to
 *cl_MethodComplete(currentSender, currentE, rv)* and its work.

Comment: right, I edited it now. thank you, best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is passing the row the user clicks on to the handler, using a lambda function:

```
btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)dgData.SelectedItem;
            rv["TimeBeg"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
            string val = rv["Id"].ToString();
            srAsync.ServClient clP = new srAsync.ServClient();
            clP.MethodCompleted += (currentSender, currentE) => cl_MethodComplete(currentSender, currentE, rv);
            clP.MethodAsync(val);
}
```

Of course you will have to add another parameter to `cl_MethodComplete`, which will be able to work on the original row:

```
private void cl_MethodComplete(object sender, srA.MethodCompletedEventArgs e, DataRowView originalRow) {
    originalRow["TimeEnd"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
    sr.ServClient clP = new sr.ServClient();
    clP.AnotherMethod(val);
    ...
```